Replacing broken drive in RAID. Creating a new partion
I am in the process of fixing a broken RAID set up. The faulty disk has been removed and a new one inserted. I have been following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xP9eUsbNF8 to help me along as I am a novice when it comes to this. The person in the video mentions copying a partition table from a working disk and applying it to the new one using fdisk.
I can't do this step as my system in this state can't find fdisk. Here are the list of available commands. Is there away for me to point my system to where fdisk should be? Is there another way around this issue with the available built-in commands? Or is it possible for me to take a working disk and the new disk from my server, connect them to a working Ubuntu machine and use fdisk to partition the new disk there, transfer back to the server and carry on?
A friend set up this server for me but unfortunately no longer around for me to ask for help. The system is running Ubuntu server with a software RAID, either RAID 5 or 6 I can't remember. But there are 4 2TB disks combining for 6TB of usable storage.
This previous question has some extra info of my system where I was asking for some information and feedback before I bought a new disk and started pulling things apart Ubuntu Server Cannot start dirty degraded array
Thanks

In order to work on the software raid array, you really need to boot off of a live-cd distribution.  You'll then have the full set of commands available to you and you will not be trying to modify a disk that you've booted off of. Unless you have a very unusual setup, just replacing the bad disk with a new identical disk should be enough to start the rebuild.

FYI, if 4 2TB disks give you 6TB usable space, then you have a raid 5 array. This is really not recommended for spinning disks of any modern size as the potential of a second disk failure during the rebuild is significant. I would strongly recommend backing up any data on the array to some external media before you do anything else.

Hey @doneal24, what would be the best way to copy the data before going ahead and making further modifications? I haven't tried to access any data directly on the server as I thought the raid array had to be running and the server wasn't showing up on the home network since the fault happened. Thanks

If you boot a live distribution, you should be able to mount the raid array - if not then your data is essentially gone and you'll have to restore from backup. If you can mount the raid, then copy the data to a network drive or an large enough usb disk.
